# Unable to send percent character "%" in the SMS body in Kannel

Tags: kannel

I have kannel installed on my Server and I am using it to connect to an SMS Gateway using SMPP. When I am trying to send an SMS with `"%"` the SMS is not sent. But without `"%"` it works fine. Thanks

I have found a solution by converting the message to HTML using `urlencode($message)`

Cheers ^_^

Comment: It's not really converting to HTML, it's [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) but yeah, that was exactly what's necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe kannel is XML and as such, you must escape a percentage `%`.

Try replacing `%` with `&#37;`

Comment: I have found a solution by converting the message to HTML using `urlencode($message)`

Cheers ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve it by changing the character-set default by adding following in your kannel.conf file

```
alt-charset = "ASCII"
```

Comment: The problem may be of encoding-GSM or UTF. and this alt-charset falls back into ASCII. The best way is to use charset=UCS-2  and encoding=2.

Answer (score 0):

use http method,

```
CALL METHOD cl_http_client=>if_http_client~escape_url

  EXPORTING

       unescaped = I_MESSAGE

   receiving

       escaped   = temp_str
     .
```

`i_message` is a message without URL content. input message along with special characters to this method, it will convert those characters which will avoid error.

Comment: please fix just about everything about your answer. whatever you're trying to say is not understandable because of your complete lack of grammar, also according to the Kannel docs, your syntax and called functions are nonexistant.

Answer (score 0):

try using %25 instead of %
  this is based on url encoding.
it worked for me